# prometheus fedration cluster data synchronization logic

Tags: prometheus, monitor

I have multiple prometheus monitoring systems.
They are aggregated to the center via fedration configuration.

The configuration of the center and the secondary federation is as follows.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'federate'
    scrape_interval: 180s
    honor_labels: true
    metrics_path: '/federate'
    params:
      'match[]':
        - '{__name__=~". +"}'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "X.X.X.X:9102"
        labels:
          datacenter: 'XXXXX'
          city: 'XXXX'
```

I run `count(max_over_time (node_cpu_seconds_total{city!="Mycity"}[1h])) by (city)` to count
the total number of servers in the central and secondary federation.

Why is the total counted in the center different from the total counted in the secondary federation?

What are the factors that affect the inconsistent data?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be me executing ```count(max_over_time (node_cpu_seconds_total{city="Mycity"}[1h])) by (city) ```to count the data between the center and the secondary federation

Comment: Run `max_over_time (node_cpu_seconds_total{city!="Mycity"}[1h])` in Prometheus Console to see all matching time series and inspect the label values af them. I think you'll find your answer there.